# Wifi 6 Intel AX200 in Kernel 5.4 Not Working Properly, Intermittent

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, 20.04, iwlwifi

I have a MSI MEG-Ace x570 Mobo with built in Wifi, I also have a Ubit Wifi card. They are both AX200 Wifi 6 Intel cards and I have downloaded the firmware and updated my lib/firmware files under the direction of a plethora of suggestions.

I have read many posts, such as [Locating Drivers for Intel AX200 Wireless on 5.1 Kernel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518571/locating-drivers-for-intel-ax200-wireless-on-5-1-kernel), [Intel iwlwifi core release](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/core_release) and [iwlwifi fails to load firmware on stable kernel (5.4) and latest (5.6)](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/85377), regarding this problem as well as others that are similar, but ultimately this is working intermittently at best, and with no knowledge of what solved/caused the problem each time. By this I mean I can download and install drivers in the lib/firmware and reboot and it doesn't work. Then do nothing and reboot again and it works, then open Windows (which always sees the drivers) play games for 2 days, then reboot Linux and it doesn't work. Then I reboot Ubuntu and it still doesnt work then two days later it works, then i reboot straight to Ubuntu and it doesnt work. Doesn't work means I get the no wifi-adapter found. This is usually coupled with a `network UNCLAIMED` message from:

```
lshw -C net
```

So what I have done currently is plug in an ethernet cable, this seems fairly stable, however due to location of the desktop in question the ethernet connecton is from a laptop acting as a WiFi --> Ethernet router.

I would very much appreciate any troubleshooting assistance and then a clear understanding of what the steps are doing such that I can see what the problem is. It is curious to me that Windows just works, i.e. not a hardware problem. Also that the only success I have in seeing my built in MoBo Wifi is when the other WiFi card is plugged in, i.e. I either have two WiFi options or no options.

If the above doesn't constitute a 'proper' question then my question is this.
'Why is my Intel 6 AX200 WiFi adapter built in to MSI Meg-ACE x570 MoBo not working, unless I install a separate Ubit Intel 6 AX200 Wifi card, at which point both work intermittently?'

Please see attached screenshot of `lshw -c net` and additional drivers:

[image: here]

**Edit:** I turned my PC back on and disabled the built in Wifi from the Bios. This seems to have given me just the network card please see attached image for lshw -c net output and device drivers:

[image: lshw -c net]

Comment: In Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers -> make a screenshot and edit your question. Also add the whole output of sudo lshw -c network

Comment: Hi Kannzzmm2,

here is the screenshot [https://ibb.co/HdG88j8] with the information, I hope this helps. Let me know if you need anything else

Comment: is not available, edit your question and post the screenshot and output of the command sudo lshw -c network

Comment: Apologies, try now. It said I wasn't allowed but uploaded it anyway