# Ubuntu 20.04 Reinstall Is Really Buggy

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, partitioning, wireless, grub2

So I have a dual boot with a 500GB SSD and a 2TB HDD.

I wanted to share the SSD between windows and ubuntu. I installed windows, then linux. But linux installed itself on the HDD, since I didn't specify any partitions at install.

So I went into windows and shrunk the SSD windows partition to 200GB. Then I booted into the ubuntu installer,and I deleted the 2TB HDD partition with linux, and installed linux on the 300GB freed from windows.

Now It is having all kinds of problems that don't even make sense, and weren't there with the first install of linux. To be clear I used the exact same bootable USB stick with ubuntu 20.04.

The screen would go black before login and just sit there. Reseting the physical power button on the front of the case, would cause the screen to directly to login, and then it was okay graphics wise. That I realized because I need to download the Nvidia driver through the software updater.

Then wifi was not even an option in settings. I couldn't find it at all to turn it on. I tried booting into safe mode, and just tried rebooting a few times. Eventuall the wifi worked but was extremely slow. I did all the system updates. Wifi still extremely slow. The solution in this link improved the wifi to where it is usable now. Still think it's slow. [Ubuntu 20.04 Network Performance Extremely Slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230525/ubuntu-20-04-network-performance-extremely-slow)

This seems to be on ongoing issue with the wireless chip in my motherboard (Asus Tuf 550 wifi) and the Intel AX200 wifi card. I found this question that was never answered: [Wifi 6 Intel AX200 in Kernel 5.4 Not Working Properly, Intermittent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259003/wifi-6-intel-ax200-in-kernel-5-4-not-working-properly-intermittent)

Several apps from ubuntu software got permanently stuck in snap during install, and I had to look up and manually disable the snap process to install over.

Frequently, the grub screen either doesn't respond at all, or just gets stuck after moving the cursor down one option.

What is going on? Should I try reinstalling ubuntu? Or should I start over again, wipe all partitions, install windows,then linux? Or should I just keep trying to solve these individual problems by googling them one by one and trying whatever works?

Comment: Advice: Reinstall Ubuntu. And get out of the habit of calling it "unbuntu"

Comment: what should I call it? Also why would reinstalling it have caused these problems? I'm really confused about this.

Comment: If you have more than one disk, it is always best to do custom install and exactly specify what should be on what partition.